# Name for the preimage of a boundary

Tags: homological-algebra, homology-cohomology

Suppose $C_\bullet$ is a chain complex and $c_i\in C_i$ is a boundary, that is
$c_i=d(c_{i+1})$ for some $c_{i+1}\in C_{i+1}$.

What is the 'usual' term for $c_{i+1}$?

Comment: There is no natural choice. You can always add an arbitrary cycle to $c_{i+1}$ and get the same result.

Comment: @Tunococ: that isn't the question.

Comment: Oh I see. Sorry I misunderstood.
So I guess the answer would be a preimage?

Comment: in de rham cohomology this would be a "potential" or "primitive" or even "integral". Just wanted to see if there is a favored term.